# Service class not updating database when called within Service Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am working on Java Spring MVC project. When the Controller calls the method in ServiceImpl class (updateAttempt()) which in turn calls DAOImpl class, the update happens and I see the updated data in DB.

But when the loadUserByUserName (which is present in ServiceImpl class) calls updateAttempt() method in same ServiceImpl class, it doesn't throw any error or exception, but data never gets updated in DB.

PersonController.java

```
    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes({ "mob_Number"})
    public class PersonController implements Observer, InitializingBean{

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

        private PersonService personService;

        @Autowired(required=true)
        @Qualifier(value="personService")
        public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
            this.personService = ps;
        }

        public PersonController(PersonService personService){
            this.personService = personService;
        }

        public PersonController(){

        }

          @RequestMapping(value="/submitVerificationCode",method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String submitVerificationCode(@RequestBody String json){
......
          this.personService.update_User_Verification_AttemptCount(userVer.getMobile_Number(), no_Attempts);
                 //this call updates the data in DB
    }


}
```

PersonServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService, UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonServiceImpl.class);  

    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    private PersonService personService;

    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @Autowired
    private Observer observe;

        @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update_User_Verification_AttemptCount(String mobile_number, int count){
        this.personDAO.update_User_Verification_AttemptCount(mobile_number, count);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mobile_Number)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {



            this.update_User_Verification_AttemptCount(mobile_Number, no_Attempts);  //but this call doesn't update the data in DB

             this.getUserDetails()  //but this call returns data from DB

    }
```

PersonDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }   

        @Override
    public void update_User_Verification_VerCode(String mob_number, String verCode, Timestamp currentTimestamp){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("update UserVerification set ver_Code=:verCode, sent_Time=:currentTimestamp where mobile_Number=:mob_Number");
        query.setParameter("verCode", verCode);
        query.setParameter("currentTimestamp", currentTimestamp);
        query.setParameter("mob_Number", mob_number);
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.flush();
    }

}
```

NOTE: the get methods residing in ServiceImpl(which does select) also return values properly when the get methods called from loadUserByUsername.

Comment: I hope you are calling `commit` method.

Comment: I don't get you. `Commit` method of ???

Answer (score 1):

That is beacause your transaction does not commit when you call the methods inside the same service.

The problem there is that Spring enriches the bean with transaction behaviour by wrapping the bean inside the proxy and adding the behaviour to it. The proxy however is always created around the interface, so calling a method with `this` keyword will not propagate the desired behaviour.

a proper solution would be to repeat the dao call so to avoid the call of the same service method

```
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mobile_Number)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {  

this.personDAO.update_User_Verification_AttemptCount(mobile_number, count);

             this.getUserDetails()  //but this call returns data from DB

    }
```

One other (hacky thing) that you can do is, since you already have a  `personService` inside `PersonServiceImpl`, is to, first make sure that its injected, so add `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired private PersonService personService;
```

and than make a call through interface e.g.

```
  personService.update_User_Verification_AttemptCount(mobile_Number, no_Attempts);  
  personService.getUserDetails()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. First option still doesn't update database. I tried second option, now I am getting null pointer exception at `this.personDAO.update_user_Authentication(......` inside 'update_User_Verification_AttemptCount` of `PersonServiceImpl.java` . `personDAO` in `personServiceimpl` is getting set as null );

Comment: yes, I think that you expect that the DAO's and services will be injected even without annotating them with `@Autowire` which is not the case. The Dao is null and you should be able to fix it by adding the annotation beside the DAO as well, or in the setter as you did in the controller